# Values based on preceding rows: when x>2 then repeat 1, when x=0 for 3 consecutive rows then repeat 0

Tags: sql, postgresql, sas, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

My task:
The variables `x` and `def` are a counter and a boolean respectively. Both start at zero.

1. If at any point in time `x > 2` then `def = 1` from that point onward.
2. Now if `def = 1` then in order for it to become zero again, `x` has to equal zero for 3 consecutive periods otherwise `def` remains `1`.

I have a background in sas and am now starting to work more extensively with Postgresql:

```
data have;
input n x;
datalines;
1 0
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 4
6 2
7 1
8 0
9 1
10 0
11 0
12 0
13 0
14 1
15 2
16 3
17 4
;
run;


data want(drop=prev_: cur_m def rename=def_new=def);
set have;
retain  prev_def prev_cur_m;
if x > 2 then def = 1;
else if prev_def = 1 and x > 0 then def = 1;
else def = 0;

if _n_ = 1 then cur_m = -1;
else if def = 1 then cur_m = -1;
else if prev_def = 1 and def = 0 then cur_m = 0;
else if -1 < prev_cur_m < 3 and x > 0 then cur_m = 0;
else if -1 < prev_cur_m < 3 and x = 0 then cur_m + 1;
else cur_m = -1;

if _n_ = 1 then def_new = 0;
else if def = 1 then def_new = 1;
else if -1 < cur_m < 3 then def_new = 1;
else def_new = 0;

output;
prev_def = def;
prev_cur_m = cur_m;
run;
```

As far as I understood this can be achieved with cursors and attempted to solve the problem using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431045/how-to-calculate-a-computed-columns-value-based-on-its-previous-value-in-postgr). However, I got stuck on the step when I needed to use the values from the previous row in order to calculate the current ones. Here is the code:

```sql
create table have (
    n int,
    x int
) ;
insert into have (n,x)
values (1,0),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(5,4),(6,2),
       (7,1),(8,0),(9,1),(10,0),(11,0),(12,0),
       (13,0),(14,1),(15,2),(16,3),(17,4);
```

```sql
create or replace function calc_dpd()
returns table (
    n int,
    x int,
    def int,
    cure_m int,
    def_new int )
language plpgsql as $f$
declare rec record;
begin
    for rec in (select * from have order by n) loop 
        if rec.n = 1 then 
            def = 0;
            cure_m = 0;
            def_new = 0;
        end if;
        if x > 2 then 
            def = 1;
        end if;
--  here I need to test if def from previous row = 1 and current def = 0;
        select rec.n, rec.x
        into n,x;
        return next;
    end loop;
end $f$;
```

Comment: You need to maintain state across rows, which can be tricky but try using PostgreSQL's window functions and common table expressions (CTEs) can help manage this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PL/pgSQL can do it but you don't need its complexity and overhead to achieve what you need: it's all doable with [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html#TUTORIAL-WINDOW) in plain, declarative SQL: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/evdX7I1x)

1. [`0=all(array[])`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-ALL) checks if all elements in the array are `0`
2. [`lag(x,that_many_rows_back,0)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW) gets the value `x` from that many rows back. Or `0` if there aren't that many rows prior to this one.
3. You can also use `every()` or `bool_and()` as a window function, and combine that with a frame start clause so that the window frame only reaches 2 rows back.
4. You can define the window in place, right in `over()` clause, or separately in [`window`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WINDOW) clause. The latter is preferable if it's non-trivial or you need to re-use it.
5. [`bool_or()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.9.1.1.1) checks if any of the values up to this one met the criteria. Here it's limited to a window frame, so it only concerns the rows since the last time `def` switched off after getting 3 zeroes in `x`.
6. The `boolean::int` [cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) maps `false` to `0`, `true` to `1`.

```sql
with cte as (
    select *
      ,(x > 2) exceeded_2
      ,(every(x=0)over w1) as should_switch
    from have
    window w1 as (order by n rows 2 preceding) )
,cte2 as (
    select *
      ,sum(should_switch::int)over(order by n) def_on_period 
    from cte
)
select n,x,(bool_or(exceeded_2) over w2)::int as def
from cte2
window w2 as (partition by def_on_period 
              order by n);
```

| n | x | def |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 4 | **3** | **1** *first x>2* |
| 5 | 4 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 0 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | **0** | 1 |
| 11 | **0** | 1 |
| 12 | **0** | **0** *third zero in x* |
| 13 | 0 | 0 |
| 14 | 1 | 0 |
| 15 | 2 | 0 |
| 16 | 3 | 1 *x>2* |
| 17 | 4 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the ways you *could* do the same with PL/pgSQL: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/bBQmWGww)

1. The `cure_m` and `def_new` are gone - the spec only described behaviour for `n`, `x`, `def`.
2. This keeps your [loop over `have`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING), retaining 2 previous `x` values in `prev_x` and `prev_x2`.
3. [`If..elsif`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) only updates `def` in the two situations you described.
4. [`0=all(array[a,b,c])`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-ALL) checks if all 3 values are zero, which is used to zero-out `def`.

```sql
create or replace function calc_dpd()
returns table (
    n int,
    x int,
    def int )
language plpgsql as $f$
declare rec record;
        prev_x  int:=0;
        prev_x2 int:=0;
begin
    def = 0;
    for rec in (select * from have order by n) loop 
        if rec.x > 2 then 
            def := 1;
        elsif 0=all(array[rec.x, prev_x, prev_x2]) then
            def := 0;
        end if;
        return query select rec.n, rec.x, def;
        prev_x2 := prev_x;
        prev_x  := rec.x;
    end loop;
end $f$;

select * from calc_dpd();
```

| n | x | def |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 4 | **3** | **1** *first x>2* |
| 5 | 4 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 0 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | **0** | 1 |
| 11 | **0** | 1 |
| 12 | **0** | **0** *third zero in x* |
| 13 | 0 | 0 |
| 14 | 1 | 0 |
| 15 | 2 | 0 |
| 16 | **3** | **1** *x>2* |
| 17 | 4 | 1 |

Comment: [Posting separately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25209) as a fundamentally different solution, to complete the context. [Here's a performance test on 300k rows](https://dbfiddle.uk/Np7wy1QK) showing that it doesn't perform as well as [the plain SQL with window functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78129169/5298879). This could probably be improved to close that performance gap a bit, but so could the other one, widening it back again.

Comment: There's also another option of [`with recursive cte as ()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE) (which are actually iterative), that could emulate this loop logic in plain SQL.